# strtok() crashing program after function calling it is called more than once

Tags: c, strtok

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out why strtok() is crashing my program

```
main()
{
    NodePtr root, cwd;
    char line[128] = {'\0'};
    char command[16] = {'\0'};
    char pathname[64] = {'\0'};
    char dirname[64] = {'\0'};
    char basename[64] = {'\0'};

    root = (NodePtr)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    gets(pathname);

    strcpy(root->name, "/");
    root->nodeType = 'D';
    root->childPtr = NULL;
    root->parentPtr = NULL;
    root->siblingPtr = NULL;

    mkdir(&root, pathname);
    mkdir(&root, "/abc/fa");
}
```

when I call mkdir the first time, everything works as expected (more specifically using strtok()).  But once mkdir gets called the second time, my program crashes when mkdir is called.

```
    void mkdir(NodePtr *root, char pathname[64])
    {
        char dirname[64] = {'\0'}; //only local variable for dirname
        char basename[64] = {'\0'};  //only local variable for basename
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int cut = 0;
        int numOfDir = 0; //number of directories
        int len = 0;  //length of entered pathname
        char* tok; //temp value to tokenize string and put it into dirPath

        char** dirPath;  //an array of strings that keeps the pathway needed to take to create the new directory

        NodePtr newNode;
        NodePtr currNode;
        NodePtr currParentNode;

        tok = "\0";

        ........

        printf("tok: %s\n", tok);
        tok = strtok(pathname, "/");   //start first tokenized part
        strcpy(dirPath[i], tok);  //put first tokenized string into dirPathp[]
    //  printf("string: %s\n", dirPath[i]);
        i++;
        while(i < numOfDir)
        {
            tok = strtok(NULL, "/");
            strcpy(dirPath[i], tok); //put tokenized string into array dirPath[]
    //      printf("string: %s\n", dirPath[i]);
            i++;
        }
         ..........
```

My program specifically breaks at

```
tok = strtok(pathname, "/");
```

Did strtok keep the input from the first call to mkdir and that's why it's crashing?  Pretty new to strtok so im sorry for the confusion.  thanks!

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) for it?  It says *"On a first call, the function expects a C string as argument for str, [....]In subsequent calls, the function expects a null pointer"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `strtok` itself wrong, but you *are* using C string literals wrong.

```
void mkdir(NodePtr *root, char pathname[64])
```

This function prototype is equivalent to `void mkdir(NodePtr *root, char *pathname)` and should be written that way.  I mention this because it's important to understand that you are passing strings into `mkdir` by *reference*.

```
mkdir(&root, pathname);
mkdir(&root, "/abc/fa");
```

On the first call, the `pathname` argument is set to point to the `pathname` variable in `main`, which is in writable memory, so everything works.

On the second call, the `pathname` variable is set to point to the string literal `"/abc/fa"`, which is in read-only memory, so you crash.  You would get the same crash if you did *anything* in `mkdir` that attempted to modify the array pointed to by `pathname`, via a library function or otherwise.

The simplest available cure is to write

```
char pathname2[64] = "/abc/fa";
```

in `main`, and then pass *that* to `mkdir`; this causes the compiler to generate a copy from the string literal to another writable character array.  More sophisticated approaches are possible, and even advisable, but I'd have to know a lot more about what your larger goals are.

Comment: thanks for the reply!  I see what my problem is.  Would I be able to set `pathname` to NULL instead of making a second `pathname2`?  Im going to have to call mkdir() an unspecified number of times so I'm hoping I could just reuse the string pathname

Comment: You could reuse the `pathname` buffer, sure, but by copying other strings into it (with `strncpy` or `memcpy`), not by setting it to NULL.

Comment: N.B. other things you probably should know about are `strdup` and `PATH_MAX`.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks @Zack, I'll probably end up using strncpy.  Appreciate the help